# Como crear una tarea programada CRON en linux

Tags: php, mysql, cron, crontab

tengo una tarea programada que ejecuta un script en php y me verifica en base de datos MYSQL si hay otras tareas programadas y cual es su status.

Tengo entendido que para crear una tarea debo hacer lo siguiente `crontab -e` en la linea de comandos de linux y editar el archivo pero lo que busco es agregar una nueva tarea crontab desde el mismo codigo php.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando ejecutas el comando `crontab -e` se edita un archivo en `/var/spool/cron/{usuario}`, donde `{usuario}` es el nombre de usuario que ejecuta el comando.

Sabiendo esto, puedes ejecutar los comandos desde PHP para agregar las tareas programadas que necesites en el crontab, algo así:

```
<?php
$tarea = "00 12 * * * scriptEjecutar.php";
$usuario = "usuarioLinux";
//Agrega al archivo
echo exec("echo '$tarea' >> /var/spool/cron/$usuario");
//Instala el nuevo crontab
echo exec("crontab /var/spool/cron/$usuario");
?>
```